# Why Option component re-renders itself after click on any option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making Quiz app in React and I got stuck in a problem where Option component gets re-render itself after clicking each option.

Here is the code

**App.js**
Main app

```
export default function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0)

  // Fetching questions
  useEffect(() => { 
    async function fetchQuestions(){
      const res = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&category=18&difficulty=medium")
      const data = await res.json()
      setQuestions(data.results)
    }
    fetchQuestions()
  }, [])

  // Checking answer on clicking any option
  const checkAnswer = (option, questionIndex) => {
    if(option === questions[questionIndex].correct_answer){
      setScore(prevScore => prevScore+=5)
      console.log("correct")
    }
    else{
      setScore(prevScore => prevScore-=1)
      console.log("incorrect")
    }
  }
  
  // Main Screen
  return (
    <QuizScreen questions={questions} score={score} checkAnswer={checkAnswer} />
  )
}
```

**QuizScreen.js**
Component for rendering quiz screen

```
export default function QuizScreen(props) {

  // Setting questions
  const question = props.questions.map((ques, index) => {

    // storing options
    const opt = []
    opt.push(ques.correct_answer)
    opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[0])
    ques.incorrect_answers[1] && opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[1]) // if option 3 available
    ques.incorrect_answers[2] && opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[2]) // if option 4 available

    // Arranging options in random order
    for(let i=0; i<opt.length; i++){
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))
        let temp = opt[i]
        opt[i] = opt[j]
        opt[j] = temp
    }

    // Setting options
    const option = opt.map(opt => <Option key={nanoid()} option={opt} questionIndex={index} checkAnswer={props.checkAnswer} />)

    // Rendering Questions
    return (
      <div className="ques-container" key={nanoid()}>
          <p className="ques-title">{ques.question}</p>
          {option}
      </div>
    )
  })
  
  // Main Screen
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.score}</p>
      {question}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Option.js**
Component for rendering option buttons

```
export default function Option(props) {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)

    const btnStyle = {
        backgroundColor: selected ? "#D6DBF5" : "#FFFFFF"
    }

    return (
        <button 
            className="ques-option"
            onClick={() => {
                props.checkAnswer(props.option, props.questionIndex)
                setSelected(prevState => !prevState)
            }}
            style={btnStyle}
        >
            {props.option}
        </button>
    )
}
```

I tried to make Option component separately, but it did not work out

Comment: You are updating the state of the options component everytime you click on the button which triggers the re-render.

Comment: Why wouldn't it re-render? You're changing its state!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this around a useMemo

```
const question = useMemo(() => {
  return props.questions.map((ques, index) => {

    // storing options
    const opt = []
    opt.push(ques.correct_answer)
    opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[0])
    ques.incorrect_answers[1] && opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[1]) // if option 3 available
    ques.incorrect_answers[2] && opt.push(ques.incorrect_answers[2]) // if option 4 available

    // Arranging options in random order
    for(let i=0; i<opt.length; i++){
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1))
        let temp = opt[i]
        opt[i] = opt[j]
        opt[j] = temp
    }

    // Setting options
    const option = opt.map(opt => <Option key={nanoid()} option={opt} questionIndex={index} checkAnswer={props.checkAnswer} />)

    // Rendering Questions
    return (
      <div className="ques-container" key={nanoid()}>
          <p className="ques-title">{ques.question}</p>
          {option}
      </div>
    )
  })
}, [props.questions])
```

Comment: Are you sure this solved your problem, after using a useMemo() to QuizScreen.js component? The reason for re-rendering of option component when clicking on any option is that you're updating the state of the same component and parent component(App.js). When react updates the state, it triggers to re-evaluate and re-render the component if something needs to be reflected on the screen.